# How to tell if my Wi-Fi is connecting using 802.11n?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have an 802.11n compatible adapter and router set to transmit using the N protocol (all settings on auto).
I'd like to find out if I'm actually using it or if I am connecting with the a/b/g protocols.

I'm using Windows 7. Router is Cisco Linksys 1200N.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to see clear solid indicator, simply hover over connected wireless network. You can find *Radio Type* in tooltip.
[image: Tooltip of Wireless Network]
In the screenshot, you can see that my *Radio Type* is *802.11g*.

Comment: I guess I was hoping for a clearer indicator. As I said in a comment to the other answer, it was the 54Mb that got me suspicious. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: 802.11n can connect at lower speeds than 150mbps. 150 is a common _maximum_, but often conditions force a lesser speed.

Comment: This Answer is wrong. You can't tell for sure from the rates, and you got the rate threshold wrong anyway. 802.11g (and 802.11a) maxes out at 54mbps, so anything higher than that is a sign you're on something post-802.11g (could be proprietary things like bonded super-G 108mbps, or Airgo MIMO-G if you gear supports that), but not necessarily N. Also, there are many N-specific rates that are lower than A/G's max 54mbps.

Comment: @Spiff See the update..

Comment: @SachinShekhar That update is a great answer all by itself. If you edit again to remove everything that came before it and make that update your whole answer, I'd happily change my downvote to an upvote. But the idea of looking at rates is misguided, and your specific text about interpreting rates (right before your update section) is outright wrong on several points.

Comment: This no longer seem to work in Windows 10, hovering over the connection doesn't bring up anything.

Comment: The "radio type" is not a clear indicator of the current connection -- it just tells you what hardware you have.

Comment: In windows 10, click on connection properties, the band in use is displayed there.

Comment: And......"connection properties" would be located......where?

Answer (score 24):

Answer from [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/507250/how-to-check-wifi-networking-standard-of-current-connection):

```
C:\Users\kuba>netsh wlan show interfaces

There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : Wireless Network Connection 2
    Description            : DW1520 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
    State                  : connected
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : 802.11g         <-- the currently negotiated value
    Authentication         : WPA-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Connection mode        : Auto Connect
    Channel                : 11
    Receive rate (Mbps)    : 54
    Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 54
    Signal                 : 82%
    Profile                : xxxx

    Hosted network status  : Not started
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I disabled my N adapter's N capability in the driver settings, and this command reports Radio type: G, which is correct. The label Radio type is misleading, though. Upvoted!

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Network and Sharing Center and select Change Adapter Settings. Right-click your wireless adapter and click "Status". It should say somewhere there whether you're using Wireless-N, Wireless-G, etc.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the "Status" dialog doesn't tell you what kind of wireless you are using.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about that, it does say it is connected at a speed of 54Mb which makes me suspicious that it's not N.

Comment: Mine does not say anything about the radio type either.  It does say 54Mb.  Running "netsh wlan show interfaces" does tell me I am using 802.11a.  This means the estimated speed is not a good indicator to determine connection type.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 7 the status box doesn't seem to pop up but if you mouse over the connection link a box appears that says 802.11n if you are on n.